# how to get diff filenames with output

Tags: diff

is there a way for diff to return the filenames of the files being compared aswell as the output, for example:

instead of :

```
17c17
<     free ((qu -> vals) - 1);
---
>     free (qu -> vals);
```

I am looking for:

```
17c17
file1.c
<     free ((qu -> vals) - 1);
---
file2.c
>     free (qu -> vals);
```

is it possible?

THanks

Answer (score 3):

the `-u` switch does include the filenames:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "    free ((qu -> vals) - 1);" > file1.c
echo "    free (qu -> vals);" > file2.c

diff -u file1.c file2.c
```

output:

```
--- file1.c 2014-03-13 17:46:43.000000000 -0500
+++ file2.c 2014-03-13 17:46:43.000000000 -0500
@@ -1 +1 @@
-    free ((qu -> vals) - 1);
+    free (qu -> vals);
```

Comment: If you want only file name and no unified context `diff -u0 file1.c file2.c`